# How to modify regex for phone numbers and accept only digits

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, phone-number

I have this following regex method for the jquery validate plugin.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("phoneUS", function(phone_number, element) {
    phone_number = phone_number.replace(/\s+/g, ""); 
    return this.optional(element) || phone_number.length > 9 &&
        phone_number.match(/^(1-?)?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})-?[2-9]\d{2}-?\d{4}$/);
}, "Please specify a valid phone number");
```

Currently, its validating against phone numbers in this format : 203-123-1234

I need to change to validate like this: 2031231234

Does anyone have a quick and easy solution for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace

```
phone_number.match(/^(1-?)?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})-?[2-9]\d{2}-?\d{4}$/);
```

with this

```
phone_number.match(/\d{10}/);
```

`\d` means match any digit

and

`{10}` means 10 times

Comment: What happened to the 2-9 constraints on certain characters?

Comment: Thank you, this seemed the easiest route to go. I'm already limiting the field by 10 numbers in the input box - but this gives the customer a message when they haven't entered enough characters.

Comment: what are the 2-9 constraints?

Comment: @jrutter ... In your original regex, it was validating only against the numbers 2-9 as the 1st number in each *section* based on `[2-9]`s.  Not sure you needed that, given `123` in your `203-123-1234` example.  If you just need to validate 10 numbers, regardless of the #s, you can use the answer I gave.

Comment: @jrutter, the 2-9 constraint are the `[2-9]` bits in your original regex. There are two places in there where a `1` digit is not allowed (following the optinal `-` characaters), and this makes the `\d{10}` regex invalid as a replacement, since it allows `1` to be placed everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Getting rid of all those `-?` sequences is probably the quickest way - they mean zero or one `-` characters.

That will reduce it to:

```
/^(1)?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})[2-9]\d{2}\d{4}$/
```

whih can be further simplified to:

```
/^1?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})[2-9]\d{6}$/
```

If you also want to disallow the brackets around area codes, you can further simplify it to:

```
/^1?[2-9]\d{2}[2-9]\d{6}$/
```

(and, technically, it won't match the literal `203-123-1234` since the character immediately after that first `-` has to be 2 thru 9, so I'm assuming you were just talking about the *format* rather than the values there).

Comment: What are the 2-9 constraints?

Comment: @jrutter, see my comment to Jason's answer. A simple `\d{10}` is not equivalent to the regex you had since there are certain positions that are not allowed to be `1`.

Answer (score 2):

I think better approach would be changing the whole expression with simpler version, something like this:

```
/^[0-9]{10}$/
```

**Edited, Note (see comments):**

This is just a limited example of how to validate a format: 111-222-3333 vs 1112223333, not proper US phone number validation.

Comment: That's not going to honor the 2-9 constraints on certain characters, you realise? That may not be a problem for the OP, but it's something you should be aware of.

Comment: You're right, thanks for pointing it out. I should have been more direct about it. I will modify a post. This example is on how to validate a format: 111-222-3333 vs 1112223333.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want ten digits, then

`phone_number.match(/\d{10}/)`

will do it. If you want to match any of the other conditions in there (eg match both 1-2031231234 and 2031231234), you will need to add more.

As a side note, what you currently have doesn't match 203-123-1234 because the first digit after the first hyphen is a 1, and it is looking for 2-9 in that spot.

Answer (score 0):

```
([0-9]{10}) this will match with 10 digit number.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use if you want to match all formats, including 203-123-1234 and 2031231234

EDIT : I'm no regex expert, but I added "1-" support

```
/^(?:1-?)?[(]?\d{3}[)]?\s?-?\s?\d{3}\s?-?\s?\d{4}$/
```

By the way, there's a really nice AIR tool for regex, it's called RegExr and you can get the desktop version here http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/desktop/ or use the online version http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ . There's also a "community" section that contains a lot of useful working regex. That's where I took that one.

Comment: That won't match 1-(800)-222-3333 like the original does :-)

Comment: Right! I added support for it. It's roughly tested though